# Objective-C: using if/else statement with Plist values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, if-statement, plist

I'm sure this is really basic but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong please? I'm working in xcode. I'm trying to make different parts of my view appear depending on values saved in a property list. If the value assigned to a particular UITextField is equal to zero then I want to hide that UITextField. I'm trying to do this like this. gross is the name of a UITextField:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
gross.text = [array objectAtIndex:7];

if ([array objectAtIndex:7 == 0]) {
    gross.hidden = YES;
}
else {
    gross.hidden = NO;
}

[array release];
```

I think the problem is something to do with how I've wrote the if/else statement. I know this is really basic but I don't quite understand where I'm going wrong. So Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is that a typo on the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code should read:

```
   NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
   gross.text = [array objectAtIndex:7];

   if ([[array objectAtIndex:7] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        gross.hidden = YES;
   } else {
        gross.hidden = NO;
   }
   [array release];
```

This assumes that the object at index 7 of your array exists and is a string. If it's actually an NSNumber, then you should instead use the conditional

```
if ([[array objectAtIndex:7] intValue] == 0) {
```

Note the above line works for a string where the text contains an int, such as `@"0"` or `@"7"`.

Comment: thanks for the reply and explanation. I used your 2nd if statement to make my code work. I'm still a little confused over the string/array issue. I guess my plist - which is created automatically through saving data in the program - is made up of an array of strings where the text therein are ints. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([[array objectAtIndex:7] intValue] == 0)
```

First mistake is position of closing `]`. And second one is you probably have NSString in array, as you have assigned that in text property. So you need to convert it to int by using `intValue`.

Answer (score 2):

If your array contains nsstring then your condition should look like:

```
if ([[array objectAtIndex:7] intValue] == 0) {
...
```

or

```
if ([[array objectAtIndex:7] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
```

1st condition will work also if your array contains NSNumbers (not likely in your case as you assign array elements to text property), but will fail if string is not a valid number - in that case intValue will return 0 as well.

2nd condition will work fine if you're sure that your elements are strings and you want to compare exactly with @"0".

---

Your condition is equivalent to

```
if ([array objectAtIndex:0])
```

because == operator has greater priority and evaluates to 0. Comparing array's element to 0 directly also does not make sense as NSArray cannot contain nil objects anyway

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It helps clarify the problems I was having

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to get the length of the array first and make sure that it has enough elements and then start accessing the elements themselves.